# Multiple Dynamic upload control with model binding

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to create multiple file upload controls with model binding. MVC Core supports IFormFile and IFormFileCollection, but I want to bind file name and path to model which generates that file Upload controls on the basis of condition. Here is one more twist: the controls are dynamically generated, so asp-for/ name is like Model[i].ParentList[i].ChildList.File1. So how can or can we do this?

Thanks in advance.

I have tried to use IFormFile and List but didn't get any value but model can show me file name only

```
@switch (Model.docTypeNames[i].professionCompliances[j].DocumentProperty[k].DatatypeName.DatatypeName.ToString().ToUpper())
{
    case "ALPHANUMERIC":
        `<input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.docTypeNames[i].professionCompliances[j].DocumentProperty[k].Name" id="@Model.docTypeNames[i].professionCompliances[j].DocumentProperty[k].Name" value="@Model.docTypeNames[i].professionCompliances[j].DocumentProperty[k].value" />`
        break;

    case "DOCUMENT":
        `<input type="file" asp-for="@Model.docTypeNames[i].professionCompliances[j].DocumentProperty[k].Name" id="`@Model.docTypeNames[i].professionCompliances[j].DocumentProperty[k].Name" value="`@Model.docTypeNames[i].professionCompliances[j].DocumentProperty[k].value" />`
        break;

    default: 
        `<partial name="_stringPartialView" model="`@Model.docTypeNames[i].professionCompliances[j].DocumentProperty[k]" />`
        break;
}
```

Comment: Did you set the `enctype` to 'multipart/form-data' in the form? `<form asp-controller="..." asp-action="..." method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Yes, problem is with multiple upload controls asp-for / name.

Comment: Yes i have added all the required things but problem is with multiple upload controls with dynamic name property.e.g. Model[0].DocName[1].FileName[1]